# How to load Web Worker from memory cache in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-worker

Edit: unfortunately I cannot reproduce this issue anymore. I guess it may just have been some weird glitch in my browser which caused this behaviour.

My apologies if I wasted anyone's time.

Original question below.

---

I created my app with `create-react-app`, which uses `webpack@5.64.4`.

I have a web worker that is loaded as follows, following guidance on https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/

```
export function createWorker() {
  return new Worker(new URL('../worker/my-worker.ts', import.meta.url));
}
```

This works perfectly fine, except for one caveat: it always fails when there is no internet connection, even if the worker is already in the cache. This breaks the offline experience for my app.

In the network logs, I can see that we always send a network request to check for an updated worker chunk. The server would reply 304 NOT MODIFIED, after which it works correctly. However, if the server cannot be reached, the script is not loaded and we fail. Other chunks are served correctly from the memory cache, without calling the server.

Comment: First of all, are you setting `Cache-control` headers correctly? Have you checked if Webpack (or something else) adds any cache-busting query strings or headers?

Comment: Are you using serviceworkers in your app? If so, they can cache this asset for you. Serviceworkers allow a better control over cached items. Sometimes, it's better not to rely on the browser for some cache strategies.

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce this behaviour anymore. I added an edit on top of the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript code for **sw.js**, the serviceworker file which will intercept network requests and serve them from cache:

```
const CACHE_NAME = "my-app-cache-v1";

self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request).then(response => { //if the response was successful, clone it and store it in the cache
            if (response.status === 200) {
                caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(cache => {
                    cache.put(event.request.url, response.clone());
                });
            }
            return response;
        }).catch(() => { //if the request fails, try to serve it from the cache
            return caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
                return response || fetch(event.request);
            });
        })
    );
});
```

To register it, call this on your page:

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js");
    });
}
```

Note that the serviceworker will be active in any page under the root of your domain, not only in the pages that call this registration.

You can see in the devtools if the network request was served from the network, browser cache or serviceworker, to confirm it is working.